# How to make flexslider square pagination

Tags: flexslider

I would like to change the circle pagination dots in flexslider with squares.  I have tried adding

```
.flex-control-paging li a{ list-style-type: square;}
```

with no luck.

Anyone know how I can change the circle to a square?

Answer (score 1):

Change all border radius values to "0"